# QGIS: How to add text to the main map canvas?

Tags: qgis

I'd like to be able to add simple text - unassociated with any layer - to the main map canvas.  This does not seem available at 3.22.3, nor have I seen it in earlier versions.

This would be similar to ***Layout > Add Item > Add Label***, but without having to go into the Print Layout.

Searching the docs, plus an internet search, turned up nothing.

Comment: Is an [`Annotation Layer`](https://north-road.com/2021/10/21/introducing-annotation-layers-in-qgis-3-22/) or a `Decoration` _(View -> Decorations -> Title/Copyright)_ what you are looking for?

Comment: I like this because you can add items - such as a scale bar - in addition to text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with Qgis version 3.22:
--> view/ toolbar / 'annotation toolbar'
[image]